# Irreducible representations (over $\mathbb{C}$) of dihedral groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

> Find  number of complex irreps of the group $D_n$. Find dimension of the irreps.

I know that

1. The number of complex irreps of a finite group is equal to the number of conjugacy classes of the group.
2. All the reflections are conjugate to each other in case $n$ is odd, but
3. they fall into two conjugacy classes if $n$ is even. But there are $n$ rotations in $D_n$. I can't find the number of conjugacy classes for these.
4. The number of 1-dimensonal complex irreps is equal to $[D_n:D_n^\prime]$. I don't know anything about the commutator subgroup of $D_n$.
5. The matrices for elements of $D_n$ have the following form:
   $$R_k=\pmatrix{\cos{\frac{2 \pi k}{n}}&-\sin{\frac{2 \pi k}{n}}\\
                  \sin{\frac{2 \pi k}{n}}& \cos{\frac{2 \pi k}{n}}}$$
   $$S_k=\pmatrix{\cos{\frac{2 \pi k}{n}}& \sin{\frac{2 \pi k}{n}}\\
                  \sin{\frac{2 \pi k}{n}}& -\cos{\frac{2 \pi k}{n}}}$$

$R_k$ is a rotation matrix, expressing a counterclockwise rotation through an angle of $2\pi k/n$. $S_k$ is a reflection across a line that makes an angle of $2\pi k/n$ with the $x$-axis.

This helps me to find all $2$-dimensional real irreps, but what about the complex ones?

Answer in my book:

"If $n=2k$, then there are $4$ 1-dimensional  complex irreps and $(k-1)$ 2-dimensional complex irreps;

If $n=2k+1$, then there are $2$ 1-dimensional  complex irreps and $(k+1)$ 2-dimensional complex irreps."

Comment: Hint: Most of the rotations have a centralizer of index two, with obvious exceptions. This should enable you to calculate the number of conjugacy classes consisting of rotations

Comment: [This](http://www.bens.ws/papers/representationDihedral.pdf) might be helpful for you.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson   I could not use your hint. Explain more detail please

Comment: There are $n$ rotations. At most two of these are central in $D_{n},$  only one is central if $n$ is odd. The other rotations fall into conjugacy classes of size $2.$

Comment: @nadia-liza, what is $D_n^\prime$? Moreover, why fact #4 is true?

Comment: Could you please tell me which book were you using, thank you.

Comment: Your book is wrong it should be:  "If n=2k, then there are 4 1-dimensional complex irreps and (k−1) 2-dimensional complex irreps;

If n=2k+1, then there are 2 1-dimensional complex irreps and k many 2-dimensional complex irreps." in other words the last k+1 should actually be k

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is one way to get the conjugacy classes of $D_n$ and irreducible representations over $\mathbf{C}$.

**Setup**

First I will fix some notation. A presentation of $D_n$ is $\langle r, s\mid r^n = s^2 = 1, sr=r^{-1}s\rangle$, which means we can pin down $D_n$ as a group of rotations $\{ 1, r, r^2\ldots r^{n-1}\}$ together with a bunch of reflections $\{ s, sr, sr^2\ldots sr^{n-1}\}$. (In what follows I will frequently be sloppy and implicitly use the identifications $r^{-i} = (r^i)^{-1} = r^{n-i}$.)

### Analysis of conjugacy classes of $D_n$

To figure out the conjugacy classes, we can just use brute force. Every element is $r^i$ or $sr^i$ for $0\leq i < n$, so it's not too hard just to write down every possible conjugation:

\begin{array}{rlclcl}
\text{Conjugate} &r^i &\text{by}&r^j &:&(r^j) r^i(r^{-j})=r^i\\
                 &r^i &\text{by}&sr^j&:&(sr^j)r^i(r^{-j}s)= sr^is=r^{-i}\\
                 &sr^i&\text{by}&r^j &:&(r^j) sr^i(r^{-j}) = sr^{-j}r^ir^{-j} = sr^{i-2j}\\
                 &sr^i&\text{by}&sr^j&:&(sr^j)sr^i(r^{-j}s) = r^{i-2j}s=sr^{2j-i}\\
\end{array}

**Conjugacy classes of rotations**

The first two rows tell us that the set of rotations decomposes into inverse pairs $r^i$ and $(r^{i})^{-1}$, i.e. the classes $\{1\}, \{r, r^{n-1}\}, \{r^2, r^{n-2}\},\ldots$

Counting these, there are $\frac{n}{2}+1$ when $n$ is even (note that $r^{n/2}$ is its own inverse) and $\frac{n+1}{2}$ when $n$ is odd.

**Conjugacy classes of reflections**

Now observe from the third and fourth lines of the table that $sr$ is conjugate to $sr^3, sr^5, \ldots$ while $s$ is conjugate to $sr^2, sr^4,\ldots$ and these **two** sets are disjoint if $n$ is even. However, $sr$ is conjugate to $sr^{n-1}$ (via $r$) so if $n$ is odd, all the nontrivial reflections are in **one** conjugacy class. (You said you already knew this but I'm putting it here for completeness.)

Together, this brings us to the total number of conjugacy classes of $D_n$:
\begin{array}{rl}
\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)+2 = \color{#090}{\frac{n}{2}+3}&\text{for }n\text{ even}\\
\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)+1 = \color{#090}{\frac{n+3}{2}}&\text{for }n\text{ odd.}
\end{array}

### Analysis of irreducible representations of $D_n$

**One dimensional irreducibles**

The commutators of $D_n$ look like $[r^i, sr^j]$ or the inverse of such, and

$$[r^i, sr^j] = r^{-i}(sr^j)r^i(sr^j) = sr^{2i+j}sr^j = (r^i)^2$$ so the commutators generate the subgroup of squares of rotations. This means $G/[G,G]$ has order 2 if $n$ is odd (since all rotations are squares) or order 4 if $n$ is even (since only half the rotations are squares). Now you can use your fact #4, which tells us that we have precisely 2 ($n$ odd) or 4 ($n$ even) irreps of dim. 1 obtained from pulling back those from $G/[G,G]$.

**Other irreducibles**

This is related to your item #5. We can define some 2-dim'l representations over $\mathbf{R}$, namely

\begin{array}{ccc}
r&\mapsto&\pmatrix{\cos(2\pi k/n)&-\sin(2\pi k/n)\\
                 \sin(2\pi k/n)&\cos(2\pi k/n)} \\
s&\mapsto&\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}
\end{array}
for $0\leq k \leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$. We would like to know if these rep'ns are irreducible if we consider them as matrices over $\mathbf{C}$.

They are reducible if $k=0$ or $k = n/2$ (can you decompose them?). If $k$ is different from $0$ or $n/2$, a quick computation shows that the matrix for $r$ has distinct complex eigenvalues $\pm e^{2\pi ki/n}$ with corresponding eigenvectors $\pmatrix{1\\-i}$ and $\pmatrix{1\\i}$. The spans of each e-vector are the only candidates for invariant subspaces, but the matrix for $s$ interchanges the two eigenspaces, so there are no invariant subspaces and thus these repn's are irreducible.

**Final count**

We have 2-dim'l irreps for each integer $1\leq k < \frac{n}{2}$, specifically we have $\frac{n}{2}-1$ for $n$ even and $\frac{n-1}{2}$ for $n$ odd. If we count these with the 1-dim'l irreps, we have

\begin{array}{rl}
\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)+4 = \color{#090}{\frac{n}{2}+3}&\text{for }n\text{ even}\\
\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)+2 = \color{#090}{\frac{n+3}{2}}&\text{for }n\text{ odd.}
\end{array}

which matches up with the number of conjugacy classes, so we must be done by your fact #1. (Also, we can verify that the sum of squares of the dimensions of the irreps is $2n$ in both cases.)

Comment: How do we know that we will get the number of one dimensional irreps from the commutators?

Comment: @Omar Shehab In the case of a 1-dimensional rep, we get a homomorphism from the group to the multiplicative group of the field. This homomorphism sends each commutator to the identity (because the multiplicative group of the field is abelian).