# how many one-dimensional representations does $D_n$ have?

Tags: representation-theory

Here by $D_n$ I mean $D_{2m}$, where $m$ is the number of sides on the regular polygon.  So the symmetries of a square would be $D_8$.  Obviously, there is the trivial representation (determined by the identity element of $D_n$), but what are the others?  And in general, is there a systematic approach to figuring it out or does it just come down to experience (which I sorely do not have)?

Comment: See the answer of Daenerys Naharis [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707355/irreducible-representations-over-mathbbc-of-dihedral-groups).

Comment: Note also that the one-dimensional representations of a finite group $G$ are precisely the irreducible representations of $G/[G,G]$. Since this is an abelian group, there are precisely $|G/[G,G]|$ such representations. Given one of the standard presentations for $D_n$, it is fairly easy to determine the group $D_n/[D_n,D_n]$.