# How to build the character table of $D_{2n}$ where $n$ is even?

Tags: representation-theory

So I'm supposed to build the character table of $D_{2n}$ for even $n$. 
$G=D_{2n}= \langle x,y| x^n=y^2=1,\,  yxy^{-1}=x^{-1}\rangle$, and the commutator$[y,x]=x^{n-2}$, where $n$ is even, so $G'=\langle x^{2(\frac{n}{2}-1)} \rangle \cong C_n$, thus the Abelization, $G/ G'\cong C_2$. And I suppose, at this point I should somehow apply Frobenius reciprocity, but I don't think I really understand it at this point.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: $G'$ is cyclic of order $n/2$, not $n$, right?

Comment: Right, so the Abelization is $D_{2n}/C_{n/2} \cong D_n$, right? So if n/2 is odd then the character table is the same for $D_{2n}$ and $D_n$, otherwise I need to keep dividing the order by 2. Is this correct?

Comment: $G/G'$ is abelian, which $D_n$ isn't (for $n\ge3$). If you want to read a treatment, instead of trying to figure it out on your own, you could look at http://math.webgirand.eu/pdf/dvp_agreg/Dn_en.pdf or http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~jm/wiki/Representations/Dihedral or https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_dihedral_groups or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707355/irreducible-representations-over-mathbbc-of-dihedral-groups

Comment: Isn't the abelianization either $C_2$ or $C_2\times C_2$ according to whether $n$ is odd or even? When $n$ is even we get four distinct homomorphisms from $G$ to $\langle -1\rangle$ because the relations won't constrain the choice of the images of $x$ resp. $y$ at all.

Comment: @Jyrki, note that OP is only asking about the case where $n$ is even.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks. But then the abelianization is always the Klein four! Just as well, as we get the four linear characters from my previous comment.

Comment: So, Máté, had a look at the sites I listed?

Comment: Yes, it was very helpful, I'm sorry I didn't react earlier! Thank you!

Comment: Good. If you can now answer the question (and if you are convinced that it isn't a duplicate of an earlier question on this site), then let me encourage you to write up what you now know, and to post it here as an answer.

Comment: You could do that today.

Comment: I definitely will, I'm sorry that it takes me this long, but I'm working. Please be patient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G=D_{2n}\geq H=⟨x^{n-2}⟩$, where $H$ is the commutator subgroup. Now if we factorize G by H, we get $G/H \cong ⟨x,y| x^2=y^2=1, xy=yx⟩\cong C_2\times C_2$. The order of this group is 4, so obviously the number of 1 dimensional representations must be 4:

$ \chi_{id}$, the trivial representation,$ \chi_{2}$ takes value $1$ on $id \in G$ and $x^i, i =1,2,...,\frac{n-1}{2}$ and $-1$ on $y$ and $yx$, $\chi_3$ and $\chi_4$ are $(-1)^i$ for $ i=0,1,...,\frac{n-1}{2}$ and $\chi_3 (y)=1$, $\chi_4 (y)=-1$, $\chi_3(xy)=-1$, $\chi_4(xy)=1$.

Now we can construct the further representations with induction. We will use the fact, that
$$\chi\uparrow_H^G = \sum_{[t\in G/H], t^{-1}gt\in H}\chi (t^{-1}gt)$$

Let $\xi_n$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity. Then
for $ 1\leq s \leq \frac{n}{2}-1$, $\chi_{\xi_n ^s}(id)=2$ (these are 2 dimensional representations) and on $x^i, i=1,...,\frac{n-1}{2} $ it is $\xi_n ^i+\xi_n ^{-i}$, $\chi_{\xi_n ^s}(y)=\chi_{\xi_n ^s}(xy)=0$.

We can use Frobenius reciprocity to check this character table.